# How to remove package filter?

Tags: filter, package

How do I disable a package filter? I keep getting this message....

```
Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.0_rc2'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
     Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all make sure you have installed **build-tools-23.0.0** using the sdk manager.

Then open the build.gradle file at app level and remove the 'rc2' part from the line `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"`

This is how I have solved the same issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Best answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: and for those of you who do not know how to install build-tools-23.0.0 like me, click on SDK manager in Android studio, Android SDK->Switch to SDK tools tab->Launch Stand Alone SDK Manager->check Obsolete->Install Build Tools Version 23

Answer (score 9):

Solved!!!
I was facing the same issue and after searching for quite a long time, I found this way around:

1. open your cmd
2. go to sdk dir
3. if `./tools/android list sdk -e` prints id: 1 or "tools" there is an update for the sdk tools available
4. `./tools/android update sdk -u -a -t tools` installs/updates the sdk tools (it reinstalls if already installed)

It will ask y/n. Choose yes, it starts installing.

Finally what **solved my problem** is to download this [rar file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91444818/23.0.0_rc2.rar) (containing the 23.0.0_rc2 sdk files), and extract it inside sdk->build-tools.

[image: android sdk license screen shot]

Comment: any better answer is appreciated

Comment: It worked for me too. My problem was { Ignoring unknown package filter 'source-24'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install. }

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue it was resolved after fixing my syntax in my build.gradle.
One of my closing brackets was in the wrong place.

Hope this helps

Comment: This issue could happen when updating SDK from command line.  Not necessarily Gradle-related.