# App getting crashed in version 5.0

Tags: android, sdk, build-tools

The problem I am facing is that my android application works well on devices  4.4.2 and below, but crashes on devices having Lollipop(5.0) and its corresponding higher versions.I know that its somehow related to the build tools in my gradle file,but still not able to figure out the problem.Could someone please help me out with this.

This is my gradle file,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vs.vertosys"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter() {}

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    compile 'com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:+'
}
```

Comment: can you post error??

Comment: no any error in logcat but app will be crashed in lollipop

Comment: show your logcat which error you get

Comment: set your build tool version to 23.1.1 and let us know

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi  when i used build tool version 23.1.1 then its show error.       **Loading SDK information...
Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.1.1'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove package filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501126/how-to-remove-package-filter)